# What in my Activity is causing this Android.Views.InflateException?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

It only started happening recently after I moved some of the elements in my layout around. I can share the XML code too if you think that would help solve the problem.

Here's the Activity that caused the exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
p1:layout_width="match_parent"
p1:layout_height="match_parent"
p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
p1:background="@drawable/pickcitybackground">
<ImageView
    p1:src="@drawable/pick"
    p1:layout_width="60dp"
    p1:layout_height="60dp"
    p1:id="@+id/pick"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    p1:layout_marginTop="90dp" />
<ImageButton
    p1:src="@drawable/austinbutton"
    p1:layout_width="60dp"
    p1:layout_height="60dp"
    p1:id="@+id/austinButton"
    p1:background="#02ffffff"
    p1:scaleType="centerCrop"
    p1:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="210dp" />
<ImageButton
    p1:src="@drawable/nashvillebutton"
    p1:layout_width="60dp"
    p1:layout_height="60dp"
    p1:id="@+id/nashvilleButton"
    p1:scaleType="centerCrop"
    p1:background="#02ffffff"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    p1:layout_marginTop="265dp" />
<ImageButton
    p1:src="@drawable/newyorkbutton"
    p1:layout_width="60dp"
    p1:layout_height="60dp"
    p1:id="@+id/newyorkButton"
    p1:scaleType="centerCrop"
    p1:background="#02ffffff"
    p1:layout_marginTop="265dp"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="210dp" />
<ImageButton
    p1:src="@drawable/sanfranbutton"
    p1:layout_width="60dp"
    p1:layout_height="60dp"
    p1:id="@+id/sanfranButton"
    p1:scaleType="centerCrop"
    p1:background="#02ffffff"
    p1:layout_marginTop="435dp"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />
<ImageButton
    p1:src="@drawable/seattlebutton"
    p1:layout_width="60dp"
    p1:layout_height="60dp"
    p1:id="@+id/seattleButton"
    p1:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
    p1:background="#02ffffff"
    p1:scaleType="centerCrop"
    p1:layout_marginTop="435dp" />
```

The stack trace:

```
    Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException:  ---> Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 182250012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 74MB until OOM
  at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 182250012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 74MB until OOM
  at at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
  at at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
  at at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
  at at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
  at at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
  at at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
  at at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:86)
  at at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:82)
  at at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:78)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
  at at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
  at at md54421ba596fa8cc5324701d9bb904102d.pickCityPage.n_onCreate(Native Method)
  at at md54421ba596fa8cc5324701d9bb904102d.pickCityPage.onCreate(pickCityPage.java:29)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:152)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5301)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:723)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:613)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
  at at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
  at at md54421ba596fa8cc5324701d9bb904102d.pickCityPage.n_onCreate(Native Method)
  at at md54421ba596fa8cc5324701d9bb904102d.pickCityPage.onCreate(pickCityPage.java:29)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:152)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5301)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:723)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:613)
  at Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 182250012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 74MB until OOM
  at at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
  at at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
  at at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
  at at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
  at at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
  at at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
  at at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:86)
  at at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:82)
  at at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:78)
  at ... 25 more
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x000a7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:12083
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00068] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:31
  at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (System.Int32 layoutResID) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-24/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:5253
  at Quickies.Android.pickCityPage.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0000e] in /Users/michaelsloan/Desktop/Quickies/Android/Quickies/pickCityPage.cs:28
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-24/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2550
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:e8fa207e-6c2f-4c69-899e-9bfde46df162 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
  at at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
  at at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
  at at md54421ba596fa8cc5324701d9bb904102d.pickCityPage.n_onCreate(Native Method)
  at at md54421ba596fa8cc5324701d9bb904102d.pickCityPage.onCreate(pickCityPage.java:29)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:152)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5301)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:723)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:613)
  at Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
  at ... 23 more
  at Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 182250012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 74MB until OOM
  at at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
  at at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
  at at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
  at at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
  at at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
  at at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
  at at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
  at at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:86)
  at at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:82)
  at at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:78)
  at ... 25 more
```

Comment: It's related to ImageButton id.

Comment: post you layout xml

Comment: I posted the XML layout. Any ideas? I would love some direction! I'm currently reading how to [efficiently load large bitmaps so I don't get this exception](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/) @MarcoPierucci

Comment: You may as well read [link] (https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have something in your layout that requires a lot of memory. Probably bitmaps, I don't know without XML layout.

> OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 182250012 byte allocation with 4194304 free

Answer (score 0):

Your images are too large. You should consider using an image loader library (I recommend Glide) to load the images, rather than just letting Android do it (because Android is pretty bad at it.)

EDIT: My `GlideImageView`:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

/**
 * Created by Zhuinden on 2016.05.07..
 */
public class GlideImageView
        extends ImageView {
    public GlideImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public GlideImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public GlideImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public GlideImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    int drawableResource = 0;

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        TypedArray a = null;
        if(defStyle != 0) {
            a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.GlideImageView, defStyle, 0);
        } else {
            a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.GlideImageView);
        }
        drawableResource = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
        a.recycle();

        ViewUtils.waitForMeasure(this, new ViewUtils.OnMeasuredCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMeasured(View view, int width, int height) {
                if(!isInEditMode()) {
                    if(drawableResource != 0) {
                        Glide.with(getContext()).load(drawableResource).dontAnimate().into(GlideImageView.this);
                    }
                } else {
                    setImageResource(drawableResource);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And

```
public class ViewUtils {
    public interface OnMeasuredCallback {
        void onMeasured(View view, int width, int height);
    }

    public static void waitForMeasure(final View view, final OnMeasuredCallback callback) {
        int width = view.getWidth();
        int height = view.getHeight();

        if(width > 0 && height > 0) {
            callback.onMeasured(view, width, height);
            return;
        }

        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                final ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
                if(observer.isAlive()) {
                    observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                }

                callback.onMeasured(view, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private ViewUtils() {
    }
}
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="GlideImageView">
        <attr name="image_resource" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: This is my first time hearing about image loader libraries but they seem self-explanatory. A quick search led me to [this](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/universalimageloader) one for Xamarin.

Comment: Personally I created a custom view back in the day which loaded the image after `onMeasure` was done using Glide. Never used `ImageView` because it is stupid and can run out of memory out-of-the-box.  I would have posted the code, but I'm from my phone and on my quest to fix my Internet at home :)

Comment: I'm making my app using C# with Xamarin, so hopefully I can use your solution for some guidance.

Comment: I've been considering using an online image resizer. Won't that do the job?

Comment: I have my doubts. I'd just use UIL

Comment: It didn't work. I need to reduce the size of my ImageButtons too. Can this be done with UIL?

Comment: yes, although I think all my "image buttons" were always image views with selector backgrounds.

Comment: You can set backgrounds to be selectable? I don't understand.